# XNA 4 - Is there a way to open up the game with new objects without exiting

Tags: c#, xna

My issue:

I have a minesweeper downloaded from internet as a tutorial and I am trying to get it to work.

I am a xna-newbie and am trying to get a fresh grid of objects without exiting the game.

I fail doing this.

In the **Update** of the Game1.cs I have

```
  KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Delete))
            {
            Exit();
            }
```

Now the Delete works as a Key but the **Exit** only exits the game. I think I would have to get a grid that updates but it seems not updating, when I don't obviously know how to do it.

If you have a hint, let me know. I think I am looking a state changer method but the **BeginRun**, and others fail with me.

**Dispose** hangs the objects. None of these built in ones seems to update the game objects to their original state.

Comment: Is this the project you are talking about https://github.com/daegren/Minesweeper-XNA? if I understand correctly you want to clear the grid when the user press the delete button instead of exiting the game?

Comment: Both assumptions of yours were correct. I have not yet found a solution for clearing up the grid once played a round through.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a version of Visual Studio that allows me to run the project. I would probably try calling grid.Initialize()

Comment: Okay, thanks. I try too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for that game, you just need to call the `Game1.Initialize()` method and the game will reset.

Comment: Thanks. In the above code sample I replaced Exit(); with Initialize(); and it worked.

Comment: It worked by emptying the grid. Good progress I'd say. The grid however has no new content. I can open the old content again by the Initialize without the number labels so the grid looks untouched but the content not changed.

Comment: Well, looks like the grid is another topic and so on. Thanks again for your support.